# Fast and efficient way to convert string into integer

Tags: python, string, integer

I want to convert four character string `text` into 32bit integer `number`, e.g. four space string should return 0x20202020.  All string elements are ASCII.  I know that something like this works

```
number = ord(text[0]) << 24 | ord(text[1]) << 16 | ord(text[2]) << 8 | ord(text[3]) << 0
```

but it is rather slow and inefficient.  Is there any faster way?

EDIT: This is meant to part of the algorithm sending a string to LCD display via C/Assembler script.  String has to be split into list containing numbers that represent four characters each.

Regards.

Comment: maybe `id(text)` might be an option, depending on your application

Comment: What purpose does this conversion serve?

Comment: @schwobaseggl To send data to C/Assembler script which then sends it to LCD display

Answer (score 4):

You could use text => bytes => int:

```
int.from_bytes(text.encode(),'big')
```

A quick time comparison:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("int.from_bytes(text.encode(),'big')","text = 'abcd'"))
print(timeit.timeit("ord(text[0]) << 24 | ord(text[1]) << 16 | ord(text[2]) << 8 | ord(text[3]) << 0","text = 'abcd'"))
```

Output:

```
0.21847990699999997
0.4186516309999999
```

So it seems that `int.from_bytes` is roughly twice as fast as the explicit bit shifting.